# Advice on Company's Validity

Tags: job-offer

## What is going on

I was hired through Upwork to do some web development by a company, but am a bit worried about some of their practices.

## My Worries

### Weird way to transfer money

Yesterday, while searching for freelance work on Upwork, I was approached by someone looking for a candidate to work for a company. This company, IF design, or International Forum Design, gave me a rather quick interview and said they would hire me on the spot. They required that I buy some software, and they sent me a check the next day, via e-mail, with the idea being I print the check and cash it with a mobile banking app. The check wouldn't register w/ the app.

Honestly, I'm getting a little bit suspicious. While they haven't requested I pay with my own money (which would cost a little under $3000, and I would refuse at that point), I feel that this method of transferring funds seems rather crude. However, I have never worked with a client like this, and I don't know if this is a fairly common way, if not a bit inelegant, to transfer funds to buy supplies. Should I treat this odd way of transferring money as a red flag?

### Hard to find info on company

The second part is I just can't find much about the company itself. This is their website: http://ifworlddesignguide.com/. There is also a wikipedia page, but it mainly copies the website. I also understand they give out some sort of reward. However, this may have something to do with them being centered in Germany. Does anyone know more about the company IF design?

## Conclusion

While I am promised a good wage, some of their practices and their limited web presence makes me a bit concerned. I have not worked with a client like this before, and don't have the prior experience or know some proper channels that I could use to confirm the validity (or lack of validity) of this offer.

Comment: If you have to ask, it's a scam.  This one certainly is.

Comment: 100% scam, run from them.  If they wanted you that badly, they'd just give you the software.

Comment: I'm going to guess that this scam is being run by whoever you'd be buying this $3000 software from ... And they intended for you to buy the software before realizing that this 'check' couldn't be cashed or deposited.

Comment: Only red flag I needed to see is "emailed a check."  What?

Comment: Is it possible to confirm the identity of the person that is trying to hire you? The person seem shady but the company look legit because it is referenced in multiple websites, they have linked news and also, they have their logo in some pictures.

Comment: Note that upwork has some strict policy regarding payments and they do close accounts of those who make payments outside the platform. If this is a scam you may loose not only money but your account as well

Comment: This situation is shady at best. If you cannot find info on the company then I would avoid it as it smells like a scam.

Comment: If you're in the US, contact the FBI. They'd likely be interested in this kind of check fraud.

Comment: Or the check is valid, but drawn on an innocent account, you pay the money for the software, the faulty check transfer is investigated and you have to return the money that you derived from the check (plus penalty plus investigation). Sounds like a new type of "mule" scheme. Not good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very likely the 'check' they've sent you will bounce a while after you pay the sum for the software. Even if it 'posts' to your account, depending on where it's drawn from, it may bounce later on after the money's available in your account. Even cashier's checks (Especially cashier's checks).

What may happen, is that you've paid for this software - Is this a software piece you're buying directly from them? It seems like if it were popular software you'd already have or know about it - which they'll somehow benefit from, then their check will bounce, and the available funds are then removed from your account.

The end result is as if you've just sent them the money directly and the check never existed, except for you sent money out thinking you were getting reimbursed.

Comment: Yes, though I didn't mention it in my post, they did ask me to buy the software from a specific source. So, it sounds like this was their plan

Answer (score 8):

## Should I treat this odd way of transferring money as a red flag?

Yes. Any company that expects you put in your own money before paying out your first salary gets an immediate red flag.

There is literally no reason why you would have to buy a piece of software with your own money and then get a refund later, given that they can send you the license key themselves without any issues.

There is also next to no reason why a freelance company would *require* you to pay such a large sum on a piece of software, the whole point of hiring a freelancer is that they've got their own tools. It would be incredibly expensive for the company to give each of the people who do some of their work an extra $3000 to buy a specific piece of software.

You are being scammed. *Never* pay money up front unless you have a contract and absolute proof that the company is real (ie; you have been in their office) or you already trust the company because you've been working for them for long enough.

Comment: +1 EXCEPTION.  The entertainment industry often requires you to get head shots (acting) or demo disks (Voice acting, Music) et cetera, but STILL, a good rule to follow.

Comment: @RichardU Wouldn't you consider the head shot etc to effectively be advertising materials?

Comment: @PeterM some agencies have their own people, or people they like to use, and organize all of your startup expenses.  It sounds like a scam to people unfamiliar with the industry.